# How to get Textbox information from one user control to another

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have two user controls in my windows form application. In the first user control I have one "textbox" and one "save" button.
And I have "Textbox" in another user control.
when I click "save" button in the frist user control then whatever the value in the "textbox" in user control one has to display in another user control "Textbox".

I have tried like this

```
namespace project
{
    public partial class ucSample : UserControl
    {

    private double transferVolume;

    public double TransferVolume
    {
        get { return transferVolume; }
        set { transferVolume = value; }
    }

    public ucSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TransferVolume = double.Parse(txtSamplevolume.Text);
       }
    }
}
```

In another user control I am trying to write logic as shown below.

```
namespace project
{
    public partial class ucSettings : UserControl
    {
         ucSample samplevolume = new ucSample();
         public ucSettings()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void  txtvolumeMin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             txtvolumeMin.Text = samplevolume.TransferVolume.ToString();
         }
    }
}
```

Please can any one help me what mistake I am doing here. I am using property to transfer value. I am not able figure it out what is the mistake. or any other best way to do this.

Comment: I misread the question. See Michael Perrenoud's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the code reversed. Let's assume the text box in the first control is named `foo` (because we don't see that code) and let's also assume the instance of the `ucSettings` control on your form is named `ucSettingsInstance`:

in the `ucSample` control:

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged;

private void foo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TextChanged != null) { this.TextChanged(sender, e); }
}
```

in your form consume that new event:

```
private void ucSettingsInstance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ucSettingsInstance.MinimumVolume = ucSampleInstance.TransferVolume;
}
```

now we need to add a new property to `ucSettings`:

```
public double MinimumVolume
{
    get { return minimumVolume; }
    set
    {
        minimumVolume = value;
        txtVolumnMin.Text = minimumVolume.ToString();
    }
}
```

and now when the value is changed in the first control you can set the value in the second control.

Comment: I want to send textbox information in "ucSample" user control to textbox in "ucSettings". The above code is not working. I am sorry if i didn't get your concept. I am little bit confusing about "ucSettingsInstance"

Comment: @reddy: I made the assumption that `transferVolume` was the value in the text box from the first user control. If it's not then you'll need to add a property to expose that value (a simple `get` that returns the text) and use that property instead.

Comment: Yes exactly "transferVolume" is the property to get value from textbox in user control 1.

Comment: @reddy, see my update. I had a copy and paste error. In the `TextChanged` consumption on the form I meant to reference the `ucSample` instance and grab the property.

Comment: If i understand the concept form you answer, I need to use the mainfrom to get the value from usercontrol1 and send it to user control2 am i right.

Comment: @reddy: that's correct, and that's why you need to publish an event on the first user control. You can then consume that event on the first user control (which is bubbled up by the `TextChanged` event of the contained text box), grab a property value from that first user control, and then set a property value on the second user control that internally sets the text of it's contained text box.